# Launch EC2 instance with more than 8G of disk space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

It seems that by default EC2 instances get launched with an 8G EBS volume attached.

Is there an easy way to launch an instance with a bigger EBS volume?

Answer (score 2):

Sure - you can define the volume size at launch time.  If you're using the web console, it's step 4 of the launch ec2 instance wizard ("Step 4: Add Storage").  Simply edit the "Size (GiB)" value for the root ebs volume and launch as you otherwise would.

The OS will come up with an 8gb filesystem on a volume of whatever size you specified - simply resize the filesystem (amazon linux defaults to ext4, so that'd be `resize2fs /dev/xvda1` - amazon linux 2 defaults to xfs, so that'd be `xfs_growfs /`).

Voila

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can select extra storage once you creating your ec2 instance, in my case there was extra nvm-e included that I would like to use.

There is "Additional launch parameters - optional" in launch parameters.
Then you can increase [your EBS volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkyjT.png).